# How to read response code from httpClient POST in angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

My backend is only answering an "OK" with 201 code. Well, I want to read this 201 code from angular but I'm only able to read the response body: "OK". This is the code of the subscription:

```js
this.socialService.postComment(this.contentCode, comment, this.answeredComment.id).subscribe(
      value => {
        console.log(value);
        console.log(value.status);
        console.log(value.headers);
        console.log(value.body);
      }
    );
```

As you can see, I'm trying to read the status code in many ways but all of them print in console undefined but the first one, which print "OK". This is the postComment code:

```js
postComment(contentCode: number, comment: string, answeredComment: number): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('contentCode', contentCode.toString());
    if(answeredComment != null){
      params = params.append('answer_to', answeredComment.toString());
    }
    const httpOptions = { 
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }), 
      params: params,
      comment: comment,
      observe: 'response'
    };
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${environment.apiBase}/social/comments/postcomment/`, httpOptions);
  }
```

I think I'm doing something wrong. How can I read the response code?

Comment: You probably _shouldn't_ expose the whole response - the service isn't much use if it's not abstracting away the transport layer from the code that's consuming it. What you've shown (`observe: "response"`) is correct per https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response, the only problem is you're passing it as the _body_ of the request not the _options_. I'd guess you wanted `.post(url, { comment }, options)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can I pass it as the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

- What is the expected response body? Empty? An object? If so, what type?
- Do you want to check the statusCode of the response before doing something with the response? If so, what do you want to do after checking the reponseCode?
- What should be the responseType of the Oservable?
- Do you want to catch http error codes?
- Do you want to just return the statusCode?

You are using `post()` incorrectly because you are adding `comment` in your httpOptions, read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/http).
In this solution, I will return the statusCode of the response. With this example, you should be able to implement other scenarios.

```js
postComment(
  contentCode: number,
  comment: string,
  answeredComment: number | null
): Observable<number> {
  return this.http
    .post(`${environment.apiBase}/social/comments/postcomment/`, comment, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      params: {
        contentCode: contentCode.toString(),
        ...(answeredComment !== null && {
          answered_to: answeredComment.toString(),
        }),
      },
      observe: 'response',
    })
    .pipe(
      map((response) => {
        return response.status;
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right. Putting comment as the second argument and httpOptions as the third one, it works. I didn't do exactly what you post but you have put me on the right path so I will mark this answer as solution.

Comment: @Optimal have you checked on the POST error, do you get HTTP status code in `map` method?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a post request and missing data, you should change it to get request or pass it some data. You can simply try to change this:

```js
const data = {};
return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${environment.apiBase}/social/comments/postcomment/`, data, httpOptions);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the POST call produces "201 OK" response, its OK.

Then, I might setup another GET call to the server to check if that ID has been created/updated.

If, yes, then I will need to get the record returned by GET, and implement in my front-end. Otherwise, If your BACKEND is yours, you can implement further information to give you more messages.

Check below code, which I mostly use for my own purposes, only

```
 // set response code - 400 bad request
http_response_code(400);

// tell the user
echo json_encode(array(
    'passed' => true,
    'Response' => "400 bad request" . "<br>" .
         " !empty(" . "$" . "data->FIELD NAME) is NOT successful."  . "<br>" .
        " Chances are that user has entered Bad Data.",
    'userMessage' => "User creation failed. Please check your data, or try again later or just send message to helpline for support."
));
```

Comment: For the moment it's returning 201 because I'm testing it, but I want to return in the body a small explanation of the problem that may happen. For example, I could return 422 "You cannot post links.". For this reason, I want to access both, response code and response body.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @BraveOtter My code does show both HTTP RESPONSE CODE and BODY,,, isn't it..